# Win32: Debugging WlanConnect?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm writing an Windows-only app that needs to connect to various WiFi networks whose names the user will provide. For some reason, the WlanConnect(...) function returns 87, which means there's an invalid parameter, but I'm not sure which parameter's invalid, or why.

```
HANDLE wlanHandle;
unsigned long nv;
WlanOpenHandle(1, NULL, &nv, &wlanHandle);

DWORD dwResult = 0;
WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS cp;
memset(&cp, 0, sizeof(WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS));

cp.wlanConnectionMode = wlan_connection_mode_profile;
cp.strProfile = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(scannerName);
cp.dwFlags = 0;
cp.pDot11Ssid = NULL;
cp.pDesiredBssidList = 0;
cp.dot11BssType = dot11_BSS_type_independent;

PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST pIfList = NULL;
PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO pIfInfo = NULL;

// only use the first wifi interface
dwResult = WlanEnumInterfaces(wlanHandle, NULL, &pIfList);

if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    pIfInfo = (WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO *)&pIfList->InterfaceInfo[0];
    dwResult = WlanConnect(wlanHandle, &(pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid), &cp, NULL);

    if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        connected = true;
    }
}
```

How can I determine what's amiss here?

EDIT:

Adding a function definition.

```
namespace {
    // helper functions for general operations
    wchar_t* convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
    {
        wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
        return wString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706613.aspx)? It gives you a whole list of things (12 items!) that can cause an `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error. Did you check those things in your code?

Comment: `cp.strProfile = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(scannerName);` looks very suspicious. What does that code actually look like? `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` can occur if `strProfile` is NULL or a bad length. That is the only thing I see in the criteria list mentioned by the documentation that might apply to your code.

Comment: I'll amend my post and add it in there... Okay, done.

Comment: What is the actual length of `charArray`, and what data does it contain? Does `MultiByteToWideChar()` succeed or fail, and what does the output look like? You have no error handling in your code. Why is `scannerName` an Ansi string instead of a Unicode string to begin with? And are you freeing `strProfile` when you are done with `WlanConnect()`? If not, you are leaking that memory. You should consider using `std::wstring` for better memory management.

Comment: You sir are correct, it was a malformed string for my profile. Thank you!